# Extend Django Password Reset

Tags: django, django-admin

I am new to Django and looking to extend Django's default Password Reset interface to integrate with Ping Federate (single signon) and update a separate database through calling Identity API from another platform service. Based on what I describeb above, please give me some inputs on:

1) If it is wise to extend Django built-in password reset or writing my own

2) How to extend Django build-in password reset to intercept the reset password calls for making calls to other API?

Thanks!
Lian

Answer (score 0):

For custom authentication, you should probably write your own authentication backend, see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources

I would override the default password reset view(s) with my own urlconf.
Refer to: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L135